# Missing a grouping variable when creating multiple barplots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm new to `R` and `ggplot2` and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to create multiple barplots next to each other.

I have a dataset with 5 different variables:

- Variable1: **"Age"**, numeric
- Variable2: **"Gender"**, categorical, Levels: male, female, divers
- Variable3: **"DepressionSymptoms"**, categorical, Levels: none, suspected, light, medium, severe
- Variable4: **"FearSymptoms"**, categorical, Levels: none, suspected, light, medium, severe
- Variable5: **"SomaticSymptoms"**, categorical, Levels: none, suspected, light, medium, severe

All variables are in one dataframe and i have set the 3 symptom variables as factor variables.

I am able to create a bar plot for a single symptom variable color coded by gender, for example:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x = DepriSymptoms, fill = Gender)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = "Participant Count",
       x = "Symptoms",
       title = "Depression Symptom Severity by Gender")
```

**Example Barplot for DepriSymptoms:**

[image]

Is it possible to use *facet* or *group* in *ggplot2* to create 3 separate barplots like the one i made (one for Depressionsymptoms, one for FearSymptoms, one for SomaticSymptoms) next to each other?

It seems to me I am missing a variable for me to group by.

Comment: It is possible - you'll need to convert your data to long format, using something like  `tidyr::pivot_longer`.  If you post some data we can show you how to do it

Comment: Have a look at [mre] for some guidance on creating a reproducible question. The simplest thing to do is to paste you data into the question using `dput(myData)` or if your data is large, a sample of your data.

Comment: @Greg You (and @shirewoman2) were right, that was exactly what i needed. : ) The dataframe shirewoman2 created is almost exactly my dataframe, so I won't post it here again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a facetted ggplot2 graph, you'll need to have a single variable in your data.frame by which you facet or break up the data. Let's start with some example data based on your question:

```
CategoryLevels <- c("none", "suspected", "light", "medium", "severe")

myData <- data.frame(SubjectID = LETTERS[1:10], 
                     Gender = sample(c("M", "F", "divers"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                     DepressionSymptoms = 
                           factor(sample(CategoryLevels, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                                  levels = CategoryLevels),
                     FearSymptoms = 
                           factor(sample(CategoryLevels, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                                  levels = CategoryLevels),
                     SomaticSymptoms =
                           factor(sample(CategoryLevels, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                                  levels = CategoryLevels))
```

I'm guessing your data structure looks something like this. As @Greg was saying, you'll need to convert your data from the wide format (each column is a symptom) to a longer format (one column listing the symptom and another column listing the subject's response). To do that, you'll need a subject ID to link everything so that you make sure you know whose answers were whose.

```
myData <- myData %>% 
      pivot_longer(names_to = "Symptom", values_to = "Response", 
                   cols = matches("Symptom"))
```

Now that you've got your data in a long format, you can facet on the "Symptom" column and fill the bar colors by the subjects' genders.

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x = Response, fill = Gender)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "count") +
      facet_wrap(~ Symptom)
```

[image: bar plot]